# Ram configurations on a computer

Tags: upgrade, frequency, ram

I have an old computer with 3gb (3 x 1gb at 400mhz) and I am to add 2gb but I only have 1 ram slot left. Will this configuration work or do I have to go all 4 x 1gb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From past experience this should work, however this was on a newer RAM module, so I have no clue what would happen with older ones, so I wouldn't be too worried if it doesn't work!

Good luck!